# Are there any political parties in the EU (or UK) who support scrapping GDPR regulations?

Tags: european-union, gdpr

There's all kinds of parties in the European Parliament and national parliaments of individual members. Are there any parties that would like to scrap General Data Protection Regulation ([GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-1-gdpr/)) altogether and go back to privacy regulations as they were a decade ago? The question also includes the UK because they've "inherited" GDPR and haven't repealed it yet.

Comment: Interesting question. There are complaints about the associated bureaucracy and clicking orgies but I don't know of a single party who supports outright repealing the GDPR.

Comment: @quarague most likely they will not promote it as "scrapping GDPR" but as "empowering business to process their data" or "encouraging the use of business intelligence."

Comment: I think you may be overestimating how radically different "privacy regulations as they were a decade ago" were from the GDPR. Large parts of the GDPR are copy-pasted from a previous EU directive.

Comment: The GDPR was proposed twelve years ago, adopted seven years ago, and became enforceable five years ago. Ten years ago is not a long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

The German AFD ("Alternative für Deutschland", an extreme right wing party) in their program for the 2021 federal election clamored for "privacy without red tape". [Specifically  they wrote](https://www.afd-erding.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Leitantrag-Bundestagswahlprogramm-2021-Dresden.pdf)

> Die AfD fordert die Abschaffung der DSGVO und seine Ersetzung durch
> ein neues, schlankes Datenschutzgesetz zur Wahrung informationeller
> Selbstbestimmung.

Translation:

> The AfD calls for the abolition of the GDPR and its replacement by a
> new, lean data protection law to protect informational
> self-determination.

i.e. repealing the GDPR and replacing it with a "lean privacy law" (which would still include a way to give and retract consent for data storage, but with no additional detail given how this will be implemented). That this would require Germany to leave the EU is in their eyes probably a feature and not a bug.

Comment: Is there any more detail available what this proposed new data protection law should or shouldn't contain?

Comment: @quarague their program does not have details (but then that is not the point of that kind of brochure), and their website mentions privacy only in connection to logging in or applying for party membership. That is as deep as I am prepared to search.

Comment: Interesting that even AfD doesn’t seem to support a complete laissez faire approach.

Comment: @JonathanReez they are a populist party, and privacy is quite popular in Germany. Laissez fair (which in the minds of their supporters would mainly benefit some faceless US companies, which I have to admit is not too far off the mark) would not be something that wins them elections.